# Block all action perform on element and its child after disabling it

Tags: javascript

I want to block all actions to be triggered on a particular element and all its child too. I tried code below, in which I have a button and one `div` having a `p` tag with default text. So on button click i disable the the div. And want to block all actions to be performed on element which is disable and its child too. But i have modify function which modify text. event after disabling div if pass we any of its child element it get affected I don't want it to be affected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         function modify(ele){
            ele.html("modified");
         };
         
         function clickHandler(){
            $('#div *').attr('disabled', true);
            modify($("p"));
         }
      </script>
      <button onclick = clickHandler()>Show</button>
      <div id="div">
         <p>default</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for disabled attribute and prevent the operation.
\

```js
function modify(ele){
    var containerDiv = $('#div');
    if(!containerDiv.attr('disabled') || !containerDiv[0].contains(ele[0])){
       ele.html("modified");
    }
 };
         
 function clickHandler(){
    $('#div').attr('disabled', true);
    modify($("p"));
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <button onclick = clickHandler()>Show</button>
      <div id="div">
         <p>default</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```